# redirect gives wrong list of results

Tags: php

When the number of results is one greater than the total loss is entered correctly, but one is subtracted from the list. For example: Found 12 results but only 11 are listed:

```
    $goto = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$results = mysql_num_rows($query); 
if($results == 1){    
    header('Location: movie.php?id='.$goto['id']);}

echo '<p><h2>Results for search "'.$_GET["search"].'": </h2></p>';
echo '<hr />';
echo "Found ".$total." result(s).</p><br>";

echo '<ol class="list">';


while ($resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$titulo = $resultado['title'];  

echo '<li>';
$link = 'http://localhost/lab/movie.php?id=' . $resultado['id'];
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: @andrewsi $goto is the associate array returned from the query. $total however appears to be undefined in this block of code.

Comment: @thatidiotguy - I saw `$goto` just after I posted, and removed it from my comment to hide my shame.

Comment: @andrewsi No shame is necessary. It is kind of floating away from the rest of the code. But Walter, buddy, why are you printing out `$total` when you have `$results` with the exact number of rows (-1) right there. And Mike found it, see below.

Comment: @andrewsi, i'm a very novice and was trying all things possible.

Comment: Now I have a new problem: when, for example, the results are more than 5, the limit per page, and next page have only one result, it is not listed, the result is displayed as if it were one instead of to list it.

Comment: @WalterDeda - do you pass a parameter to tell the code what page of results to display? You just need to add a check in your initial if statement. `if(($results == 1) && (! isset($_REQUEST["page"])))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
$results = mysql_num_rows($query); 
if($results == 1){    
    $goto = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    header('Location: movie.php?id='.$goto['id']);}
}

echo '<p><h2>Results for search "'.$_GET["search"].'": </h2></p>';
echo '<hr />';
echo "Found ".$results." result(s).</p><br>";

echo '<ol class="list">';

while ($resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
```

Your code is getting the first record at the start, and if there's more than one entry, you're then looping through the rest of the records - binning the first one. This way, you're not populating `$goto` until you know you need it.

Comment: Now I have a new problem: when, for example, the results are more than 5, the limit per page, and next page have only one result, it is not listed, the result is displayed as if it were one instead of to list it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using up your first record pointer on this line:

```
$goto = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

If you move this line inside the `$results == 1` conditional, everything should work fine.

Right now when you get to your while loop, you are starting with the result set pointer already on the second record.